How to add a ciphersuite to HttpClient in .NET 7?
I developed a console app, in C# running on .NET 7, using the HttpClient component, which consumes a restful API whose methods are authenticated with a bearer token.
As this application is to be run on a Windows Server 2012 R2, I need some way to create a specific ciphersuite, which does not exist in this version of Windows.
These ciphers are a requirement of the TLS1.2 connection to the domain I am connecting to (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384).
How can I build and integrate these ciphers into HttpClient. Someting like this:
var handler = new HttpBaseHandler ();
handler.AddCipherSuite = CipherSuite.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 


I'm fairly sure you can't - they're tied to the configuration of Windows.

Side note: .NET 7 is already out of support - I'd suggest to upgrade to .NET 8

Use the IIS Crypto tool https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto to modify the registry on your machine. For Server 2012R2 you also need to install all the latest updates, and do note that this OS is now out of support, you should really upgrade ASAP.

I've already done it, but it only modifies the registry.
I'm not going to upgrade Windows Server, if I could do that I wouldn't have this situation.
Is there another way, with some other library?

If it's not supported there is nothing you can do. Find another supported cipher that matches what the other side supports, or upgrade. There is no other option. In theory you could write your own SChannel library to implement it, but honestly that isn't even worth thinking about.
